# how to set Metadata correctly in azure

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, azure

I tried to save Metadata by this way :

```
     public void SaveMetaData(string fileName, string container, string key, string value)
    {
        try
        {
            var blob = GetBlobReference(fileName, container);
            blob.FetchAttributes();
            blob.Metadata.Add(key,value);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            _logger.Error(e,
                "An Exception occured  with blobname = {0} and blobcontainer = {1}", fileName,
                container);
        }
    }
```

but it did not work .what should I do more ?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to call [`SetMetadata()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.windowsazure.storage.blob.cloudblob.setmetadata?view=azure-dotnet) to actually save the metadata. This is how your code should look like:

```
    public void SaveMetaData(string fileName, string container, string key, string value)
    {
        try
        {
            var blob = GetBlobReference(fileName, container);
            blob.FetchAttributes();
            blob.Metadata.Add(key, value);
            blob.SetMetadata();//This line of code will save the metadata.
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            _logger.Error(e,
                "An Exception occured  with blobname = {0} and blobcontainer = {1}", fileName,
                container);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Hi again ,if I want just one item in blob to have certain value (true) and all other items in blob have (false) value ,how can I do that ?! thanks in advance

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow Rezo! Please post a new question for this problem of yours with all the details that you can share. Thanks.

Comment: I just add new question with all details about my question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46935088/add-edit-metadata-in-azure