# Add , Edit Metadata in Azure

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, azure, metadata, azure-storage

I recently asked a question here and thanks to Gaurav Mantri I could add Metadata to blob azure .
my Code after editing in AzureBlobStorage class :

```
  public void SaveMetaData(string fileName, string container, string key, string value)
{
    var blob = GetBlobReference(fileName, container);
        blob.FetchAttributes();
        blob.Metadata.Add(key, value);
        blob.SetMetadata();
}
```

and I call it  from myController by this :

```
public JsonResult SaveMetaData(string name, string key, int id)
    {
        var uploadedFils = _FileStorage.GetUploadedFiles("images", id + "/");


if (!uploadedFils.Any())
                _FileStorage.SaveMetaData(name, "images", key, "true");
        foreach (var file in uploadedFils)
        {
            if (name == file.Name)
            {
                _FileStorage.SaveMetaData(FormatFileName(id, name), "images", key, "true");

            }
            else
            {
                _FileStorage.SaveMetaData(FormatFileName(id, file.Name), "images", key, "false");

            }
        }
        return Json("");


    }
```

the code to get uploaded file

```
public IEnumerable<Attachment> GetUploadedFiles(string container, string blobprefix)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(container))
            container = DefaultBlobContainer;

        var storageAccount = CreateStorageAccountFromConnectionString(GetStorageConnectionString());
        var blobContainer = GetBlobContainer(storageAccount, container);

        var resultList = new List<Attachment>();
        try
        {
            foreach (IListBlobItem item in blobContainer.ListBlobs(blobprefix, false))
            {
                var blob = (CloudBlockBlob) item;
                var file = new Attachment
                {
                    Name = blob.Name.Substring(blob.Name.LastIndexOf('/') + 1),
                    Size = blob.Properties.Length,
                    Extension = Path.GetExtension(blob.Name)
                };
                resultList.Add(file);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {

        }

        return resultList;
    }
```

and I call this action when I click on the desired image that I want to set as active .
for first time it works , but I don't know how to edit it for second click  ,specially this is first time for me dealing with Azure ?
the logic behind this line that : when the Gallery is empty and the users upload the first image , this image will be set automatically to active:

```
    if (!uploadedFils.Any())
            _FileStorage.SaveMetaData(name, "images", key, "true");
```

Comment: What do you mean with second and first click?

Comment: @PeterBons first click I set an image to active but the gallery has more than one image so second click will set another image to active

Comment: Can you edit your question and include code for `GetUploadedFiles` as well?

Comment: @GauravMantri I edited my question .

Comment: Thank you. Let me see if I understand it correctly: In your application, a user can upload multiple images but only one of them can be the default one (or rather active). What you want is if there's already an active image, you want to make that inactive and make another image (that the user clicks on) active. Is my understanding correct? Also, can please edit your question and explain the logic behind these lines of code: `if (!uploadedFils.Any())
            _FileStorage.SaveMetaData(name, "images", key, "true");`?

Comment: @GauravMantri yes that's totally  correct , the logic when there is no image in Gallery , and the user uploaded the first image I want to set it as active per default ,thanks

Comment: Please edit your question and explain the logic behind these lines of code: `if (!uploadedFils.Any()) _FileStorage.SaveMetaData(name, "images", key, "true");?`. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to your description, I checked your code, you need to modify your code as follows:

**SaveMetaData** method under your AzureBlobStorage class:

```
public void SaveMetaData(string fileName, string container, string key, string value)
{
    var blob = GetBlobReference(fileName, container);
    blob.FetchAttributes();
    if (blob.Metadata.ContainsKey(key))
    {
        blob.Metadata[key] = value;
    }
    else
        blob.Metadata.Add(key, value);
    blob.SetMetadata();
}
```

Based on your scenario, your image files would be uploaded to `images\{id}\{filename}`. And before you invoke the **SaveMetaData** under your controller, you need to make sure the file with the specific parameters `name` and `id` exists in your blob storage. I assumed that you need to remove the following code snippet:

```
if (!uploadedFils.Any())
   FileStorage.SaveMetaData(name, "images", key, "true");
```

**Note:** If there has no files, you could not add/update the meta data for it. Also, you just set the `name` for the parameter `fileName` without combining the `id`. Based on my understanding, the `SaveMetaData` method is used to set meta data for existing files. I recommend you move the above logic to the action for uploading the file and set the default meta data if there has no files.